# "Extend"JS Array like in traditional OO languages?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm digging deeper into JavaScript. I know it is possible to modify/enhance the behavior of JavaScript objects my modifying the prototypes.

For a special purpose I'd like to take Array and add all sorts of behavior to it. I TOTALLY get it is BAD to change all Arrays for my case. But it  regular OO language, I could just extend it, add my functions,  leave the original alone. Is there anything comparable in JS? Like, can I copy the Array prototype & put it onto another class & fiddle with that without affecting other arrays? Or any notions?

Not critical, but it would be helpful and certainly help me get a deeper understanding of JS which I am really getting into after years of Java, C++, etc.

Comment: In ES6 you _can_  extend `Array`, although this doesn't work if you try to transpile down to ES5.

Comment: `class MyArray extends Array { … }`

Comment: Javascript is one of the most duck punchable languages out there. You can simply add a new function as a property to any object. If you put it on the prototype, all objects of that type inherit it. Have you tried anything in this regard…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the Array class and implement your extra functionality as methods on that class.

Instead of using `let x = [];` you now use `let y = new myArray();`.

```js
class myArray extends Array {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    console.log(typeof this.push);
    console.log(typeof this.shift);
  }
  
  logAndAdd(variable) {
    this.push(variable);
    console.log(variable);
  }
}

let y = new myArray();

y.logAndAdd('hi');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use ES6 [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) like you would in any other OO language.

Here is an example of a class that extends the native array and adds a log method. Only issue with this is that you will have to use the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword to create a new array.

```js
class CustomArray extends Array {
 log() {
  console.log(this);
    }
}

var customArrayInstance = new CustomArray();

customArrayInstance.push(1,2,3,4,5);

customArrayInstance.log();

// Creating an array using the array constructor
//
new CustomArray(200).fill(null).log()
```

What you could also do is use [`Symbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) to extend the behavior of the native array in a non OOP kind of way. You will be basically extending the prototype of the native array in a non browser breaking way.

Answer (score 0):

I think taking a look at Javascript Iterators and their possibilities is one option.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

I have used this approach in Typescript/Angular2 to achieve array-like collections, where I can define custom push/pop/pull operations in an OO like way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, and in JavaScript we call this interface-ish thing a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
};
```

Although personally, I would generally prefer to make "method" an independent function that takes and returns an array.